# How to fix my Heroku app not building locally?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have a Heroku app that is running fine on the server, but I keep getting an error when I try to run it locally

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\username\LobbyTrackerSandbox\client\build\index.html
```

I looked and the \build directory is part of .gitignore, but the issue was not remedied when I removed it. Any help?

Comment: You've told us very little about your application, but generally directories called "build" contain compiled artifacts. Does your application have a build process (e.g. maybe via `yarn build` or `npm run build`)? Have you run that? Are you sure you want to be using the compiled artifacts in development?

Comment: I am fairly new to Heroku so I'm sorry I can't provide that much info. I tried npm run build and it said no process existed. I'm merely trying to run it using heroku local web. I am also new to this application and the developers (its 100% internal) left very little documentation